# Ъ в славянских словах

Tags: фонетика

Порой, когда знатоки приводят тут в пример старославянские слова, они употребляют Ъ явно вместо какой-то гласной. Тоже самое есть и в болгарском языке. Скажите, пожалуйста, какой звук он обозначает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько помнится со студенческих лет, буквой Ъ ("ер") обозначают так называемый редуцированный (урезанный, сокращенный) звук, который звучит (извините за тавтологию)в безударных слогах. Его трудно обозначить письменно, надо произнести. Например, слово "молоко" в окающих говорах произносится с четким обозначением каждого звука (мо-ло-ко),в акающих говорах - ма-ла-ко, а по нормам оно должно произноситься с редуцированными звуками (мъл^ко), где второе "о" произносится ближе к краткому "а", а первое "о" - еще более краткий звук, средний между А и Ы

Answer (score 0):

Вы ответили про редуцированные звуки в современном языке, а спрашивают-то про старославянский. Хотя и в старославянском он в похожих позициях (после твердого во втором предударном (и далее) и в заударном слогах). Но ведь не только. Были еще позиции, когда он не читался вовсе. И в разные периоды времени по-разному. (Пора и мне вспомнить историческую грамматику!)

Comment: Фонетику, наверное. :)

Comment: Не знаю, как сейчас. но раньше был учебник "Историческая грамматика", а там и фонетика, и собственно грамматика. Так сложилось.

Comment: А кто автор? Довольно, имхо, нелогично представлять вполне постижимую протым умом историю фонетики частью совершенно неподъемного предмета исторической грамматики. Фонетика от праиндоевропейского Адама тезисно укладывается на десяти-пятнадцати страницах, а про один какой-нибудь каузативный аорист можно тома писать.

Comment: Мы в свое время. если не ошибаюсь. занимались по Горшковой. Но это неважно. Вот из предисловия к "Исторической грамматике" Борковского

Comment: " Название "Историческая грамматика» является традиционно установившимся, но его нельзя
признать вполне точным. Историческая грамматика включает
в себя фонетику, морфологию и синтаксис. По мнению многих,
лингвистов (и для этого есть основания), грамматику составля-
ют лишь морфология и синтаксис, фонетика же образует особую-
область. Но, поскольку изучение морфологии и синтаксиса (в
особенности же первой) без знания фонетики невозможно, в этот
курс необходимо включается и фонетика."

Comment: Мда... Спасибо. Оно оказывается ещё и "традиционно". Не знал. Вот что значит недостаток образования. Но мысль интересная. *Поскольку изучение половой жизни мексиканских тушканчиков невозможно без знания краткого курса истории ВКП(б)...*

Answer (score 0):

Ответ Виктор1799 в общем-то правильный, только неполный. 
Давайте сразу рассматривать пару Ъ и Ь. Оно даже понятнее.
В дописьменный общеславянский период эти звуки, унаследованные от индоевропейских, звучали примерно как краткое У и краткое И (несмягчающее) соответственно. Однако уже к моменту первых фиксаций славянских слов (на греческом) эти звуки сильно изменились, как и вся система славянского вокализма.

К появлению письменности это были краткие гласные переднего ряда неясного качества. Обычно Ъ передают как краткое Э или Ы, что, пожалуй, лучшее из возможных приближений. Его аналог Ь (ерь) - передавал смягчающий краткий т.е. Е или И.

Неверно полагать, что эти звуки соответствовали кратким О и Е, это соответвеие возникло уже на русской почве в процессе так называемого падения редуцированных (IX-XIII век - в разных диалектах).

Со всеменам фонетика несколько менялась, современный болгарский звук более ясный, но в принципе соответствует историческому Ъ. При этом в разных языках его принято предавать по-разному. В английском, например, он считается соответвующим краткому U (в слова cup, bug). Обычная передача его русским "О" с фонетической точки зрения совершенно неверна, и объясняется не звучанием, а традицией и морфологией.

Если хочется действительно разобраться со всеми причудами русской азбуки, настоятельно рекомендую познакомится со всей историей славянской фонетики (в основном - вокализма) хотя бы в письменный период, а не коллекционировать сведенья по отдельным звукам. Она, эта история, того стоит, а главное - наступает некоторая ясность в целом, а не по частностям. Во всяком случае названия типа "йотовый юс великий" перестают быть ночным кошмаром нерадивого первокурсника-филолога.